# Google Analytics: Page views but no sessions? No page visits but positive avgTimeOnPage?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am new to GA and need help interpreting the results.  I built a simple report that shows username, # of sessions, # of unique page views, and average time on page.  I am seeing some odd results that I can't explain.

1. I have users that have 0 sessions but positive unique page views.  How can this happen?  Doesn't visiting a page automatically initiate a session?
2. I have other users with 0 sessions, 0 page visits, but a positive avgTimeOnPage.  I am at a loss to explain this.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen when you look at your AdWords campaigns in GA or from Analytics reports directly?

Comment: I voted to move this question to the respective forum, due this question is not related to programming

Comment: I'm pulling the GA data via the API.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a tricky question, this can happen due to 2 reasons:

1 .- If you are mixing different scope you can have reported with an unexpected Behaviour. For example, if you're using the dimension as Pagepath (a hit Scope) with Sessions metrics (Session Scope), this can give you page with no sessions due to the query on the database only take the first element on the sessions. In that way, the totals of sessions matches with all the other reports, in other way this report becomes incomparable. Think that is an object behind. There is an easy post explaining what happens.

https://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/misunderstood-metrics-sessions-for-pages/

2.- There is a second issue that can cause this but is way less common, that is sent only a non-interaction hit with no pageview, this can cause creations of sessions will